# Corona SDK - Black Screen On The Top Part of the app

Tags: sdk, coronasdk

in Corona SDK, i wonder how can I make my app full screen? I think almost all code samples also have a little bit of black screen on the top part of the app, until I saw business app sample, which doesn't have any of that. This is what I meant:

http://oi61.tinypic.com/33ljv69.jpg

but in business app sample they provided, it doesnt have the same problem:

http://oi59.tinypic.com/sxzknb.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the letterBox setting in Corona SDK.  You will want to Google and research things related to it (or dig through the examples).  I use this setting and with the right attributes you can get it to remove the black bars.